# can i put asp.net in css?

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-8

I need a stand alone page for search, which I have built independent of the master page and master.vb, but there is info in the.vb file I believe that has a fix for ie8 for drop down menus, and I need it in this stand alone page (which is supposed to look like the rest of the site, and does, except the dropdown menu doesn't work properly).

This is the code in the master.vb file:

```
    Dim ie8 As New HtmlMeta
    ie8.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible"
    ie8.Content = "IE=7"
    h.Controls.AddAt(0, ie8)
```

I think this is the code that makes the dropdown menu render properly in ie8. Currently it acts like there's basically no css and Is there a way I can add this to my stand-alone page maybe via some css at the top?  Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated, as is prob obv, I don't know enough about this type of thing. : )

By the way, the dropdown works in compatibility mode of IE8, but would like to find the solution we have for the main site which works fine without compatibility mode on.  Thank you in advance for your help -- if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in CSS. You need a meta tag in the head of your search page.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
</head>
```

Comment: Yes, I just found that and came in to delete my post - thank you, mccrager.